# Support extended markdown table syntax with Mkdocs

Tags: formatting, markdown, mkdocs

I have markdown tables like the following in my docs:

```markdown
+----------------------+----------------------------------------------+
| `code`               | *italics*                                    |
+======================+==============================================+
| `more code`          | | column 1 | column 2 | column 3 |           |
|                      | |----------|----------|----------|           |
|                      | | abcd     | efg      | hijk     |           |
|                      | | lmnop    | qrs      | tuv      |           |
|                      | | wx       | y        | z        |           |
+----------------------+----------------------------------------------+
| `even more code`     | Regular text that spans multiple lines       |
|                      | within this cell.                            |
|                      |                                              |
|                      |                                              |
+----------------------+----------------------------------------------+
| **bold**             | Regular text that spans multiple lines       |
|                      | within this cell.                            |
|                      |                                              |
|                      | **bolded text in a separate paragraph.**     |
+----------------------+----------------------------------------------+
```

Is there some way (e.g. with a plugin) that I can get Mkdocs to render it as a table in the resulting HTML?

The above table can be reformatted as required, but ultimately it needs to support table cells that contain arbitrary markdown within them, allowing for nested tables, paragraphs that span multiple lines, italics, etc.

Notably, [Pandoc supports this Markdown format](https://pandoc.org/try/?text=%2B----------------------%2B----------------------------------------------%2B%0A%7C+%60code%60+++++++++++++++%7C+*italics*++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++%7C%0A%2B%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%2B%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%2B%0A%7C+%60more+code%60++++++++++%7C+%7C+column+1+%7C+column+2+%7C+column+3+%7C+++++++++++%7C%0A%7C++++++++++++++++++++++%7C+%7C----------%7C----------%7C----------%7C+++++++++++%7C%0A%7C++++++++++++++++++++++%7C+%7C+abcd+++++%7C+efg++++++%7C+hijk+++++%7C+++++++++++%7C%0A%7C++++++++++++++++++++++%7C+%7C+lmnop++++%7C+qrs++++++%7C+tuv++++++%7C+++++++++++%7C%0A%7C++++++++++++++++++++++%7C+%7C+wx+++++++%7C+y++++++++%7C+z++++++++%7C+++++++++++%7C%0A%2B----------------------%2B----------------------------------------------%2B%0A%7C+%60even+more+code%60+++++%7C+Regular+text+that+spans+multiple+lines+++++++%7C%0A%7C++++++++++++++++++++++%7C+within+this+cell.++++++++++++++++++++++++++++%7C%0A%7C++++++++++++++++++++++%7C++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++%7C%0A%7C++++++++++++++++++++++%7C++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++%7C%0A%2B----------------------%2B----------------------------------------------%2B%0A%7C+**bold**+++++++++++++%7C+Regular+text+that+spans+multiple+lines+++++++%7C%0A%7C++++++++++++++++++++++%7C+within+this+cell.++++++++++++++++++++++++++++%7C%0A%7C++++++++++++++++++++++%7C++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++%7C%0A%7C++++++++++++++++++++++%7C+**bolded+text+in+a+separate+paragraph.**+++++%7C%0A%2B----------------------%2B----------------------------------------------%2B&from=markdown&to=html5&standalone=0). Maybe I can hook into Mkdoc (e.g. by making my own plugin) to render the markdown using Pandoc's syntax for it.

I would like to avoid writing inline HTML.

Comment: Check [this list](https://github.com/Python-Markdown/markdown/wiki/Third-Party-Extensions) of known extensions for Python-Markdown (the Markdown parser which MkDocs uses). Perhaps one of them will offer a solution for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to the link Waylan provided, I found an unmaintained project that provides what I needed.

I've made [a fork of the project](https://gitlab.com/WillDaSilva/markdown_grid_tables) (which I intend to maintain), and have published it to [PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/markdown-grid-tables/).

It can be installed with `pip install markdown-grid-tables`, then used by adding `markdown_grid_table` to your list of [Markdown extensions](https://python-markdown.github.io/extensions/).

Comment: could you elaborate in simple steps how to install this ? That would be very helpful !

Comment: @MyICQ I've updated the answer with a brief explanation of how to use it. It applies to Markdown tables automatically once the extension has been installed and registered, just like most other Python Markdown extensions. I hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you. If I had looked carefully at the [PyPI page](https://pypi.org/project/markdown-grid-tables/) the installation instructions are right there, at the top. One correction: adding `grid-table` fails (no module named...), should that not be `markdown_grid_tables:`  (which worked for me).

Comment: @MyICQ My apologies. The extension is registered with the name `grid-tables`, but its import name is used to register it. I'll update the answer to reflect that. Thanks for pointing that out.